# Window Replacement - Contractor Cut Out Jack Studs

Tags: windows

I'm having new windows installed on a brick facade home built in 1950. I'm concerned that the contractor ordered windows too big and is now trying to cut existing framing to fit.  They cut out the jack studs.  I now have an unsupported header. I'm very concerned and wondering if I should have them cease work and have this inspected.  They ran out to get materials and I don't know what the plan is at this point.

Additional info:  Roof is above.  One-story home.  They cut the studs on both sides.  38" between king studs.  35 5/8" wide window.

Thank you

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have questions: how wide is the window, relative to the rough opening they've created? Is there a second storey above? Did they do this on both sides?

Comment: What is above the ceiling?  Roof or second floor?  Contractor would be better off just returning windows and getting right size.

Comment: Added requested info to post.  Thank you.

Comment: Even if it's nonbearing, https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.7.4 and https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.7.5 are on your side. In the nonbearing case I wouldn't fuss over it. Maybe some 1x4 jack studs would be a good compromise in the nonbearing case. Are there roof rafters or trusses ending over the wall's top plate?

Comment: The two windows they've done are on a Gable end, so I'm guessing a truss is over it.  Thanks popham.

Comment: Since its one story and there is a truss above, it is not that bad.  But I would still try to put something to replace them.  Even 1X4 as mentioned by @popham.  Even, when non-load bearing, the header protects the window from getting squished.  Which could lead to (in the extreme case) windows jamming or glass cracking.